# Error in assigning gcs IAM permissions using nested map in terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

Im trying to assign multiple roles to different members using terraform but im running into an error.This is for assigning iam permission in GCP.
Use a combination of nested map. But the nested map became complex since Im using two different variables and use them in creating resources.

main.tf looks like this

```
locals {
 
  data_access = flatten([
    for bkt_key, bkt_value in var.buckets_data : [
      for user,roles in var.data_access : [
        for role in roles:{
        member = user
        bkt  = bkt_key
        role   = roles
      }]
    ]
  ])
}



resource "google_storage_bucket_iam_member" "buckets_data_access" {
  for_each = { for access in local.data_access : "${access.bkt}_${access.member}" => access... }
  bucket   = google_storage_bucket.tf_buckets_data[each.value.bkt].name
  role     = each.value.role
  member   = each.value.member
}
```

terraform.tfvars looks like this, Please note I'm using two different variables in the nested map of main.tf.

```
buckets_data                      = {
  "landing"                         = { 
    region                            = "nane1",
    storage_class                     = "COLDLINE",
    versioning                        = "false",
    data_tier                         = "raw",
    lifecycle_rules                   = ["retention-2years"],
    external_access                   = []
  },
  "dftemp"                          = {
    region                            = "nane1",
    storage_class                     = "STANDARD"
  },
  "curated"                         = {
    region                            = "nane1",
    storage_class                     = "STANDARD"
  }
}

data_access                           = {

"group:GCP-npe@bell.ca"= ["roles/storage.objectViewer","roles/Browser"]

}
```

error I received in my terminal

```
$ terraform plan
╷
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on main.tf line 29, in resource "google_storage_bucket_iam_member" "buckets_data_access":
│   29:   bucket   = google_storage_bucket.tf_buckets_data[each.value.bkt].name
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.value is tuple with 2 elements
│
│ This value does not have any attributes.
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on main.tf line 29, in resource "google_storage_bucket_iam_member" "buckets_data_access":
│   29:   bucket   = google_storage_bucket.tf_buckets_data[each.value.bkt].name
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.value is tuple with 2 elements
│
│ This value does not have any attributes.
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on main.tf line 30, in resource "google_storage_bucket_iam_member" "buckets_data_access":
│   30:   role     = each.value.role
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.value is tuple with 2 elements
│
│ This value does not have any attributes.
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on main.tf line 30, in resource "google_storage_bucket_iam_member" "buckets_data_access":
│   30:   role     = each.value.role
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.value is tuple with 2 elements
│
│ This value does not have any attributes.
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on main.tf line 31, in resource "google_storage_bucket_iam_member" "buckets_data_access":
│   31:   member   = each.value.member
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.value is tuple with 2 elements
│
│ This value does not have any attributes.
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on main.tf line 31, in resource "google_storage_bucket_iam_member" "buckets_data_access":
│   31:   member   = each.value.member
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.value is tuple with 2 elements
│
│ This value does not have any attributes.
```

Comment: What is `var.buckets_data`? Your variables are somehow cropped in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my understanding is correct of what you are trying to do, the following flattening is better:

```
locals {  
  data_access = merge(flatten([
    for bkt_key, bkt_value in var.buckets_data : [
      for user,roles in var.data_access : {
        for role in roles: 
        "${bkt_key}-${user}-${role}" =>  {
          member = user
          bkt  = bkt_key
          role   = role
      }}
    ]
  ])...)  # please do NOT remove the dots
}
```

then

```
resource "google_storage_bucket_iam_member" "buckets_data_access" {
  for_each = local.data_access 
  bucket   = google_storage_bucket.tf_buckets_data[each.value.bkt].name
  role     = each.value.role
  member   = each.value.member
}
```

Comment: Thank you it works, But can you give me a brief explanation on how the "merge with ellipsis" helps my use case?

Comment: @adithyar24200 Such marge changes `merge([a, b, c]...)` into `merge(a, b, c)`.

Comment: it will help in removing the duplicates?

Comment: @adithyar24200 Not sure which duplicates. Your question does not mention anything about any issue with duplicate values. If you have such problems, this is a new issue, so please make new question specific to duplicates.